# Why GPS Location do not work?

Tags: android, gps

I have four very small classes. Following are the four classes. The mobile view do not show me anything other than "Location Unavailable". And logging goes upto "Location Finder Started". Nothing else triggers.

Main Actility

```
public class CarbonTrackerMainActivity extends Activity {
     private MainView mainView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainView = new MainView(this);
    locationFinder();
    setContentView(mainView);
}

private void locationFinder(){
    Log.d("Car","Location Finder Started !!");
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    }
}
```

View of the application

```
public class MainView extends View{
    public MainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
         Paint background = new Paint();
         background.setColor(Color.GRAY);
         canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);
         Paint text = new Paint();
         text.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         text.setTextSize(15);
         canvas.drawText(DataHolder.getDataHolderObject().getLocationInTxt(), 10, 10, text);
         invalidate();
     }
}
```

Location Listener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    DataHolder.getDataHolderObject().setLocation(loc);
    Log.d("Car","Found one location!");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    Log.d("Carbon","GPS Disabled!");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    Log.d("Carbon","GPS Enabled!");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    Log.d("Carbon","GPS Status Changed!");
}
}
```

Singleton to pass variables

```
public class DataHolder {

    private static DataHolder dataHolderObject;
    public Location location = null;

    //======== Singleton Code =====================
    private DataHolder(){}
    public static DataHolder getDataHolderObject(){
        if (dataHolderObject == null)
            dataHolderObject = new DataHolder();
        return dataHolderObject;
    }
    //======== End of singleton ===================

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocationInTxt() {
        String text;
        if (location==null)
            return "Location Unavailable";
        text = "My current location is:\n" + "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() +"\nLongitud = " + location.getLongitude();
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you add permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

Comment: I added only "FINE_LOCATION". But just now i added the other one as well. Still i dont see anything. When i check maps in android it shows my location upto a some level.

Comment: Do you have the permissions? GPS-fix can take some time so you might just need to wait a bit. Try having it outside, at least not in a bunker.

Comment: Your Location is always returning null. Thats why its giving you Location Unavailable. Check my answer...It will surely help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just kept the phone closer to a window for 5 min. Then it started to work. So the code i posted do not have any problem. But still consider the answer about seeting criteria

Answer (score 1):

You are making mistake in Location. Check that your Location is null or not?

```
public void setCriteria() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        if (provider == null) {
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
    }
```

//set the criteria and check that your location is null or not

```
    if (currentLocation == null) {
        currentLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
```

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: How does this help? He is already set the provider as GPS_PROVIDER... And he is clear he would like to use GPS and not Wifi... You are just redirecting and setting the provider... This is a redundant way

Comment: problem is the listener do not trigger any methods. So how can i check the location is null?

Comment: Thankx for the code. After keeping the phone closer to window for 5 min it started working. I'll give a upvote for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also guessing the gps doesn't have enough time to lock on a location before you print the DataHolder.getDataHolderObject().getLocationInTxt() in some devices (you draw your view immediately after you start listening for location changes).

You can either draw your mainview ever x seconds with a Timer() which is a bit inefficient or even better when the location is updated in "public void onLocationChanged" change/redraw your mainview so it draws the new location.

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the phone in open space for about 50 - 100 m.. it starts giving the data...